# How to make listener re-render only if changes made on navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation, listener

I am trying to make my app only re-render when a change has been made, I have got it so that when I add a new workout, the item re-renders on the navigation back to the original page but when I go to add a new workout and click the back button without adding a new workout, the app still re-renders and adds the original workout again so it is duplicated

```js
  const [workoutSlides, setWorkoutSlides] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const didFocus = navigation.addListener(
      'focus',
      () => { load(); }
    )
    return didFocus;
  }, [navigation]);

  const load = async () => {
    try {
      const storedSlides = await AsyncStorage.getItem('workoutSlides');
      if (storedSlides) {
        const parsedSlides = JSON.parse(storedSlides);
        setWorkoutSlides(parsedSlides);
      }
      const name = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutName');
      const sets = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutSets');
      const reps = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutReps');
      const weight = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutWeight');
      if (name, reps, sets, weight) {
        setWorkoutSlides((prevSlides) => [
          ...prevSlides,
          {
            name: name,
            reps: reps,
            sets: sets,
            weight: weight,
          },
        ]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const storeData = async () => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('workoutSlides',
          JSON.stringify(workoutSlides));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    storeData();
  }, [workoutSlides]);
```

I am using react navigation and when I click the back button in the status bar, this is when it re renders the page, i'm thinking of trying to do an if statement with the navigation.addListener hook but i can't seem to figure one out, i've tried multiple ways but nothing seems to have worked

i'm still quite new to coding and this is my first project so i appreciate any help